# React and Firebase Firestore V9 Previous Page Pagination returning to "first page"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm at a loss here. I feel like I've been trying everything, and using the exact methods explained in other posts/tutorials everywhere. I understand that you need to use a cursor and set the first and last visible document so that you can start after the last, in the case of moving forward, and start BEFORE the first, in the case of moving backwards.

In my implementation, going forwards works fine. However, when I utilize the previousPage function, it returns me to the first page, despite setting the 'first visible' document. It returns to the first page even if I've already moved 3 'pages' forward.

Clearly there is something I'm not understanding here..

```
  const PAGE_SIZE = 6;
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState(null);
  const [firstVisible, setFirstVisible] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // Initial read to get first set of posts. 
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(
      collectionGroup(db, "bulletins"),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    );
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (documents) => {
      const tempPosts = [];
      documents.forEach((document) => {
        tempPosts.push({
          id: document.id,
          ...document.data(),
        });
      });
      setPosts(tempPosts);
      setLastVisible(documents.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]);
      setFirstVisible(documents.docs[0]);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const nextPage = async () => {
    const postsRef = collectionGroup(db, "bulletins");
    const q = query(
      postsRef,
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      startAfter(lastVisible),
      limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    );
    const documents = await getDocs(q);
    updateState(documents);
  };

  const previousPage = async () => {
    const postsRef = collectionGroup(db, "bulletins");
    const q = query(
      postsRef,
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      endBefore(firstVisible),
      limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    );
    const documents = await getDocs(q);
    updateState(documents);
  };

  const updateState = (documents) => {
    if (!documents.empty) {
      const tempPosts = [];
      documents.forEach((document) => {
        tempPosts.push({
          id: document.id,
          ...document.data(),
        });
      });
      setPosts(tempPosts);
    }
    if (documents?.docs[0]) {
      setFirstVisible(documents.docs[0]);
    }
    if (documents?.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]) {
      setLastVisible(documents.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `endAt()` instead of `endBefore()` and also, you should pass the order reference which is the `createdAt` to the `endAt()` method. See code below:

```
  const PAGE_SIZE = 6;
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState(null);
  const [firstVisible, setFirstVisible] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(
      collectionGroup(db, "bulletins"),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    );
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (documents) => {
      const tempPosts = [];
      documents.forEach((document) => {
        tempPosts.push({
          id: document.id,
          ...document.data(),
        });
      });
      setPosts(tempPosts);
      setLastVisible(documents.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]);
      setFirstVisible(documents.docs[0]);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const nextPage = async () => {
    const postsRef = collectionGroup(db, "bulletins");
    const q = query(
      postsRef,
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      startAfter(lastVisible.data().createdAt), // Pass the reference
      limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    );
    const documents = await getDocs(q);
    updateState(documents);
  };

  const previousPage = async () => {
    const postsRef = collection(db, "bulletins");
    const q = query(
      postsRef,
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      endAt(firstVisible.data().createdAt), // Use `endAt()` method and pass the reference
      limitToLast(PAGE_SIZE)
    );
    const documents = await getDocs(q);
    updateState(documents);
  };

  const updateState = (documents) => {
    if (!documents.empty) {
      const tempPosts = [];
      documents.forEach((document) => {
        tempPosts.push({
          id: document.id,
          ...document.data(),
        });
      });
      setPosts(tempPosts);
    }
    if (documents?.docs[0]) {
      setFirstVisible(documents.docs[0]);
    }
    if (documents?.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]) {
      setLastVisible(documents.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]);
    }
  };
```

For more information, See [Add a simple cursor to a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#add_a_simple_cursor_to_a_query).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated version of pagination which could be used for Firebase Database + NextJS/React.

> Retrieve Data

```
const PAGE_SIZE = 6;
    const [paginatedPosts, setPaginatedPosts] = useState([]);
    const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState(null);
    const [firstVisible, setFirstVisible] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const q = query(
            collectionGroup(database, "posts"),
            orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
            limit(PAGE_SIZE)
        );
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (documents) => {
            const tempPosts = [];
            documents.forEach((document) => {
                tempPosts.push({
                    id: document.id,
                    date: document.data().date,
                    title: document.data().title,
                    title_sub: document.data().title_sub,
                    text: document.data().text,
                    innerImage: document.data().innerImage,
                    goBackLink: "/research"
                });
            });
            setPaginatedPosts(tempPosts);
            setLastVisible(documents.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]);
            setFirstVisible(documents.docs[0]);
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    const handleNextPage = async () => {
        console.log('next page')
        const next = query(collectionGroup(database, "posts"),
            orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
            startAfter(lastVisible),
            limit(PAGE_SIZE));

        const documents = await getDocs(next);

        updateState(documents);
    }

    // createdAt
    const handlePreviousPage = async () => {
        console.log('previous page')
        const next = query(collectionGroup(database, "posts"),
            orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
            endAt(firstVisible),
            limit(PAGE_SIZE));

        const documents = await getDocs(next);

        updateState(documents);
    }

    const updateState = (documents) => {
        if (!documents.empty) {
            const tempPosts = [];
            documents.forEach((document) => {
                tempPosts.push({
                    id: document.id,
                    date: document.data().date,
                    title: document.data().title,
                    title_sub: document.data().title_sub,
                    text: document.data().text,
                    innerImage: document.data().innerImage,
                    goBackLink: "/research"
                });
            });
            setPaginatedPosts(tempPosts);
        }
        if (documents?.docs[0]) {
            setFirstVisible(documents.docs[0]);
        }
        if (documents?.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]) {
            setLastVisible(documents.docs[documents.docs.length - 1]);
        }
    };
```

> Render Data with Tailwind

```
<div className="flex items-center justify-center space-y-4 py-5">
    <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center space-x-2">
        <button onClick={handlePreviousPage} className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-40 h-10 text-md font-poppins font-light text-white bg-t_brown border-none rounded-full no-underline hover:bg-t_brownlight duration-500 whitespace-nowrap">
            <svg className="w-3.5 h-3.5 mr-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M13 5H1m0 0 4 4M1 5l4-4"/>
            </svg>
            Previous
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleNextPage} className="inline-flex items-center justify-center w-40 h-10 text-md font-poppins font-light text-white bg-t_brown border-none rounded-full no-underline hover:bg-t_brownlight duration-500 whitespace-nowrap">
            Next
            <svg className="w-3.5 h-3.5 ml-2" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 10">
                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M1 5h12m0 0L9 1m4 4L9 9"/>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```