# Firebase Firestore How can i read a specific amount of documents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Firestore database with React.
I was wondering if i can read a specific amount of documents every page.
For instance i've got 3 pages and each page can load 100 documents.

I know there's a `.limit()` method for a query but it's a one time load only.

Comment: I don't understand why you think limit won't work.  That's exactly what you're supposed to use for [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).  This is your only mechanism for controlling the max number of documents returned per query.

Comment: Yeah! pagination is what i looked for! Thansk alot

Comment: You may also want to check a sample of pagination using reactjs from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71864823/react-and-firebase-firestore-v9-previous-page-pagination-returning-to-first-pag/71866462#71866462).